# ActionbarSherlock - tabs unresponsive in landscape orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am currently backporting my application to make it work on device prior to 3.0 using actionbarsherlock.

If a user launches the application in portrait mode and then rotates the screen and tries to select a tab nothing happens until the user preforms another action. The current build which does this can be downloaded here (sherlock-alpha1)  http://tinyurl.com/cz95nup.

Tabs are added in the following way

```
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("tab1").setTabListener(this),false);
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("tab2").setTabListener(this),false);
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("tab3").setTabListener(this),false);
```

This also occurs if you launch the application in landscape and then use it in portrait mode (portrait tabs will not work).

It is working fine on devices running the native actionbar.

Comment: What minSDKversion are you running right now?

Comment: @Davek804 android:minSdkVersion="7"

Comment: I recently did the same thing and I didn't experience this bug. Does it still occur if you switch your minVersion to 10? What version device are you testing this on? Is it the AVM?

Comment: I have tested it on a Xperia neo v running 2.34 and I got this behaviour. I have also tested it on multiple emulators. Did you manage to test the APK?

Comment: Just tested setting the minVersion to 10 and the issue is still there. It seems the device registers the click but doesn't act upon it until you touch something else (e.g. the menu overflow button).

Comment: I just tested alpha1 on my ICS Galaxy Nexus. Not really sure how to test via AVM with a premade APK. Anyways, I dont experience the error. Launch app in portrait, move to landscape. Without touching anything else, tried clicking on Freebies, from Deals. Touch immediately registered, progressDialog fired, new tab loads.

Comment: The problem only occurs when running on devices prior to ICS which use the actionbarsherlock actionbar. On ICS it works as expected :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you handling configuration changes in the manifest?

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

If so this is not allowing the fake decor view that ActionBarSherlock installs to be re-initialized on rotation which will cause many problems.

Handling configuration changes should be used as sparingly as possible. The documentation states that [it should be used as a last resort](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

Future versions of the library will hopefully be able to account for people who choose to do this.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was unresponsive after orientation changes, not in landscape mode.
After a lot of trial and errors I've found the following solution for this bug:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
}
```

The trick is to change the navigation mode to list then change back to tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problems. I had to add these line and it is ok on AVD, don't know if it is working on real devices.

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
```